# VS Code: Command to view git remote changes?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-remote

Currently, to view remote changes on git, I do the following in the terminal.

```
git remote update
git status -uno
```

But is there a way to do this graphically in visual studio code? Perhaps through any extensions?

Answer (score 1):

the git-scm in vs code might be what you're looking for. It visuals display files that have changed, that have been staged, merge changes, etc. it comes built into vs code now. You'll also be able to synchronize these with your remote repos and visually see how many commits you are ahead of or behind in the current branch.

Comment: It does not show the list of remote commits that are waiting to be pulled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension: [Git History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory)

Comment: That appears to be for `git log`... which is for local changes only.